# Problem with class having as base class ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, actionfilterattribute

The following class creates a custom action filter named [SessionTimeout]:

```
public class SessionTimeoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly ISession _session;
    public SessionTimeoutAttribute(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        if (!ctx.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

As the implementation is now, when I go to decorate a class with [SessionTimeout] it also asks me the parameter for the constructor.

I would like to avoid this if possible.

Can someone helè me?
Thanks.

Comment: this seems like something that should be built in.

Comment: the httpcontext should be available from `filterContext` too.

Comment: @DanielA.White : 
In essence, what should I do to be able to qualify a class with the [SessionTimeout] attribute without passing the httpcontext? Could you explain me wirh a sample? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpContext` is a property of the `ActionExecutingContext` object, so you shouldn't need to pass it into via the constructor. Something like this should work (note: this is not tested).

```
public class SessionTimeoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = filterContext.HttpContext;
        if (!ctx.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cajn you take a look at this one topic ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879140/session-expire-problen-in-asp-net-core-2-2-web-app