# ASP.NET Core: session expires but user is not redirected to login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, session, cookies

This is the first time I'm using .net core so maybe I'm doing something wrong. My application does not redirect to the login page after the session is expired, obviously resulting in `Null Pointer Exceptions` when I try to read session variables.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication()
   .AddCookie(options =>
   {
      options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(180);
   });

services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(180);
   });
```

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**

If I manually delete the .AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie, than I'll be correctly redirected to the login page.

[image]

How can I obtain this behaviour?

Comment: What is the version of your .NET Core application?

Comment: @FeiHan .net core 3.x

Comment: You can try to run it on kestrel and check if same issue occur.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using the `OnActionExecuting` method of `IActionFilter` by redefining it in our custom class.

First add it to the services:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(RequestAuthenticationFilter));
});
```

Then create a custom class `RequestAuthenticationFilter` and define the `OnActionExecuting` method.

```
public class RequestAuthenticationFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public RequestAuthenticationFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// OnActionExecuting
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get("UserId");
        if (session == null)
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Login", controller = "Account", area = "Identity" }));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// OnActionExecuted
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you register the UserId key somewhere, and if you do, where did you store yours. Perhaps Login action, when the user is properly logged in?

Answer (score 2):

Taking a clue from [Sonu K's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4008833/sonu-k) answer, I have created an Attribute, so I can apply it to specific controller or action. Here is my implementation.

```
public class ValidateSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ValidateSessionAttribute() { }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var userId = context.HttpContext.Session.Get<long>(Constants.SessionKeys.UserId);

        if (userId <= 0)
            context.Result =
                new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Login", controller = "Account" }));
    }
}
```

Decorate controller with above attribute to start using it.

```
[ValidateSession]
public class SomeController : Controller
{
}
```

Comment: Nishith, thank you so much for this it works great. It's nice that it's a decorator so it can be used on any class or method.

One thing I'll add is a good way to get to your session properties. Here, I get the Session Id using the ActionExecutingContext passed as "context". If it's null, the session has expired.

int publisherId = int.Parse(context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("PublisherId"));

Comment: This approach woried great for me. I love that I can use the attribute on a class or a single method. This is a very simple and flexible approach.

Answer (score 0):

to change Identity time out from startup.cs

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    });
```

Refer to [Session Expire problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879140/session-expire-problem-in-asp-net-core-2-2-web-app)

Answer (score 0):

Add this block to `Program.cs` class

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(180);

    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

Reference: [Configure Identity services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services)